# Decrypt aes-128-ccm on NodeJS without auth tag

Tags: node.js, encryption, cryptography, aes

I`m porting some crypto code from Python to NodeJS.  I have Python example that works perfectly:

```python
from Cryptodome.Cipher import AES

key = bytes.fromhex("befe6acee59a8d3d3c97eeea8cdb9e99");
nonce = bytes.fromhex("5830b603313800002298c44124");
cipherpayload = bytes.fromhex("9f3f2d8dd339");

cipher = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CCM, nonce=nonce, mac_len=4) # mac_len 4 or 8 or 16 keeps code working
cipher.update(bytes.fromhex("11")) # commenting this line keeps code working
print("result:" + "\"" + cipher.decrypt(cipherpayload).hex() + "\""); # prints result: "011003000104" as intended
```

But NodeJS version is not working:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');

let key = Buffer.from('befe6acee59a8d3d3c97eeea8cdb9e99', 'hex');
let nonce = Buffer.from('5830b603313800002298c44124', 'hex');
let cipherpayload = Buffer.from('9f3f2d8dd339', 'hex');

let cipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-ccm', key, nonce, { authTagLength: 4 });
cipher.setAAD(Buffer.from('11', 'hex'), { plaintextLength: cipherpayload.length });
console.log('result: ' + '"' + cipher.update(cipherpayload).toString('hex') + '"');  // prints result: ""
```

All found examples about aes-128-ccm and NodeJS uses cipher.setAuthTag() with tag, but I have no authTag and Python version works correctly. I there any way to decrypt this in NodeJS?

Node version: v17.3.0
Python 3.9.2
Platform: 2021-10-30-raspios-bullseye-armhf-lite
Also tested on 64bit Debian, same result.

Edited:
Full raw network data for this question that I received from device is  `'95fe5830b603312298c44124f89f3f2d8dd3393800001a'`
brute forced tag (4 bytes let me to do this) and found tag value `'07860841'`.
I believe, the tag should be in the network data, but I can`t figure out where.

Edited 2:
Brute forced another packet, looked to many packets and found that tag is definitely not transmitting from the device. It is device developer bug.
Really there is no way to correctly decrypt data wit integrity check.

Comment: For decryption with NodeJS, you need the tag. That you don't need it for Python is because PyCryptodome allows both decryption with tag (via `decrypt_and_verify()`) and thus with integrity check and decryption without tag (via `decrypt()`) and thus without integrity check. Since you use `decrypt()` in the Python code, you don't need a tag. However, decryption without integrity checking is not allowed by most libraries for security reasons, like NodeJS, so you need the tag here.

Comment: Note that when using modes like GCM it is trivial for the attacker to modify the cipher so that the decrypted plaintext has whatever bits the attacker chooses flipped. This is one reason why a MAC is vital and not merely a nice-to-have.

Comment: Never decrypt if tag is not correct!

Comment: Thanks for warning about security, but this code is for hacking  proprietary smart home device and there is no way to get the tag. I know that it is unsafe, but im frustrated because in Python I can do this unsafe decryption and in NodeJs can't. Also in NodeJs there is separate api for checking (.final()) and update should return result whithout checking, before checking.

Comment: This hack is allowed by NodeJS for GCM, because the tag may be set after the `update()`-call. For CCM, the tag must be set before the `update()`, so this doesn't work, s. [here](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#deciphersetauthtagbuffer-encoding). You should be more frustrated that Python and NodeJS for GCM allow something like encryption without integrity check. The integrity check is the added value of authenticated encryption. Without that check, you might as well use CTR.

Comment: @Topaco thanks for explanations, S for security in IOT, you now. This code is about hacking Xiaomi Yeelight Dimmer as explained here https://github.com/nccchirag/yeelight-ble-rotary-dimmer/issues/1 The only way I see now is to get opensource JS AES-CCM library and hack it to work without integrity check.

Comment: @Aquahawk I'm afraid this scheme you just bumped into isn't actually proprietary. It's worse: it's an IoT thing defined in ZigBee, IEEE 802.15.4, Annex B "CCM*".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This answer DANGEROUS, you SHOULD check authTag**, but if you need to skip this check, jscrypto (https://github.com/Hinaser/jscrypto) helps to do this.

```js
const JsCrypto = require('jscrypto');

var key = JsCrypto.Hex.parse("befe6acee59a8d3d3c97eeea8cdb9e99");
var nonce = JsCrypto.Hex.parse("5830b603313800002298c44124");
var cipherpayload = JsCrypto.Hex.parse("9f3f2d8dd339");
var cp = new JsCrypto.CipherParams({ cipherText: cipherpayload });
var decrypted = JsCrypto.AES.decrypt(cp, key, { iv: nonce, mode: JsCrypto.mode.CCM, padding: JsCrypto.pad.NoPadding });
console.log('result: ' + '"' + decrypted.toString() + '"');
```